# Always print EAGAIN when calling accept after epoll_wait

Tags: c, epoll

I'm using epoll to monitor the listen fd event, after the EPOLLIN event occur I call accept to process,
but always EAGAIN error. Anyone can give me some suggestions? thanks!

**[log]** print the information below all the time

INFO      Jan 01 00:02:08:924 [385] poll_loop: epoll has 1 event

INFO      Jan 01 00:02:08:925 [385] poll_loop: event fd 0, event type:1

INFO      Jan 01 00:02:08:925 [385] handle_connect: fd 0,

ERROR     Jan 01 00:02:08:925 [385] handle_connect: accept returned an error 11 Resource temporarily unavailable ... retrying, listen fd:0.

**[code]**

```
    ................

        listenfd = listen_sock (port, &addrlen);
        socket_nonblocking(listenfd);
        g_epollFd = epoll_create(MAX_EVENTS);  
        register_read(listenfd);

    .................

        while (!config.quit)
        {

            int fds = epoll_wait(g_epollFd, g_Events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);  

            if (fds < 0)
            {
                log_message(LOG_CRIT, "epoll wait error %d %s, continue", errno, strerror(errno));
                continue;
            }

            log_message(LOG_INFO, "epoll has %d event", fds);
            for (i = 0; i < fds; ++i)
             {

                log_message(LOG_INFO, "event fd %d, event type:%d", g_Events[i].data.fd, g_Events[i].events);
                 if ((g_Events[i].events & EPOLLERR) 
                    || (g_Events[i].events & EPOLLHUP)
                    /*|| (g_Events[i].events & POLLNVAL) compile err*/)
                {
                    log_message(LOG_INFO, "A disconnect occurs, [fd:%d]", g_Events[i].data.fd);
                    handle_disconnect(g_Events[i].data.fd);      
                    continue;
                }
                if (g_Events[i].events & EPOLLIN)
                {
                     if (listenfd == g_Events[i].data.fd)
                    {
                        handle_connect(listenfd, ptr);
                    }
                    else if (g_dnsfd == g_Events[i].data.fd)
                    {
                        dns_poll(g_dns);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        handle_input(g_Events[i].data.fd);
                    }
                }
    ...................

    void handle_connect(int fd, struct child_s *ptr)
    {
        int connfd;
        struct conn_s *connptr = 0;
        char peer_ipaddr[IP_LENGTH]; 
        socklen_t clilen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        struct sockaddr_in cliaddr ;

        log_message(LOG_INFO, "fd %d, ");
        connfd = accept (fd, (struct sockaddr*)(&cliaddr), &clilen);

        if (connfd < 0) 
        {
            log_message (LOG_ERR, "accept returned an error %d %s ... retrying, listen fd:%d", errno, strerror (errno), fd);
            return;
        }

    ......................

#define REGISTER_EPOLL_EVENT(_fd, evt, op) \
do\
{\
    struct epoll_event epv = {0, {0}};  \
    epv.data.fd = _fd;  \
    epv.events  = evt;  /*EPOLLLT default*/\
\
    if(epoll_ctl(g_epollFd, op, _fd, &epv) < 0)  \
    {\
        /*if ((errno != EEXIST) && (errno != ENOENT))*/\
        {\
            log_message(LOG_ERR, "epool ctl set failed, fd %d, errno %d: %s", _fd, errno, strerror(errno));  \
            return ;\
        }\
    }\
    log_message(LOG_INFO, "epool ctl set sucess, fd %d", _fd);\
}while(0)


void register_read(int fd, int* evt)
{
    if (0 == evt)
    {
        REGISTER_EPOLL_EVENT(fd, EPOLLIN, EPOLL_CTL_ADD);
    }
    else if (0 == *evt)
    {
        *evt |= EPOLLIN;

        REGISTER_EPOLL_EVENT(fd, (*evt), EPOLL_CTL_ADD);
    }
    else if (!(*evt & EPOLLIN))
    {
        *evt |= EPOLLIN;
        REGISTER_EPOLL_EVENT(fd, (*evt), EPOLL_CTL_MOD);
    }
    else
    {
        log_message("event %d for fd %d is already there", *evt, fd);
    }

}
```

Comment: how are you actually handling disconnects?  I"m not seeing any way for that to adjust what you're polling on.

Comment: is there a reason you're calling epoll_wait twice?

Comment: there's a ton of code you're calling that you're not showing us that potentially makes it hard to help.  register_read  handle_disconnect and maybe others would help to be able to see

Comment: calling epoll_wait twice seems silly, but not error-inducing.

Comment: You are actually calling epoll_wait() *twice* ? BTW: is it edge-triggered?

Comment: we need to see how he calls http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_ctl to know if it's edge triggered.  BTW, the right answer is you don't want edge triggering.  EPOLLET is not your friend.

Comment: What's wrong with ET? I see it used successfully in many very common network applications.

Answer (score 1):

This line says it all:

```
INFO Jan 01 00:02:08:925 [385] poll_loop: event fd 0, event type:1
```

fd 0 is STDIN, not your listening socket. Evidently, you are adding "0" to the epoll set instead of your listening socket.

You didn't show where epoll_ctl was getting called to add listenFd to the epoll set (g_epollFd). Presumably, that's what the register_read() call above is all about.  I would expect it to look something like this:

```
int result;
epoll_event readEvent = {};

readEvent.data.fd = listenFd;
readEvent.events = EPOLLIN;
result = epoll_ctl(g_epollFd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, listenFd, &readEvent);
```

Notice that listenFd is specified as both the third parameter to epoll_ctl as well as a member var on the fourth parameter (readEvent.data.fd).

Comment: the kernel version is linux 2.6.21, It seems  a same problem like this https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/1815, but I'm not sure.

Comment: on Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-40-generic-pae it's goes well, but on Linux ralink 2.6.21 #4057, it's problem.

Comment: I'm sure now it's same problem with dev.openwrt.org/ticket/1815, but I can not upgrade the kernel directly, any other advice?

Comment: Switch to calling poll() instead of epoll for your polling mechanism. http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll

Comment: If you do eventually confirm the error, please post an answer yourself and mark it accepted so that others may benefit.

Answer (score -1):

EAGAIN is not really an error.

Please see:
[ERROR on accept: Resource temporarily unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635440/error-on-accept-resource-temporarily-unavailable)

Also, in case you're interested further reading, I highly recommend this book for a good overview of network programming with epoll.

http://man7.org/tlpi/

Comment: it's my fault, only one time calling epoll_wait acctually, and I'm using EPOLLLT mode, handle_disconnect() hasn't called

Comment: And I know that EAGAIN is not really an error, it just tells nothing should be handled, but epoll_wait tells something happen on listenfd. it's a dead loop. I meet this problem on Ralink mips board, but on my vmware ubuntu same code is ok, running very well.

Comment: epoll_ctl is called in EPOLLLT mode when calling register_read(listernfd)